# If $m$ and $n$ are integers and $mn$ is even, $m$ is even or $n$ is even.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

I'm looking for feedback on my proof of the following statement:

> "If $m$ and $n$ are integers and $mn$ is even, then $m$ is even or $n$ is even."

I tried using a direct proof method:

(1) Since $mn$ is even, $mn = 2k$ for some integer $k$. The integer $k$ must then be equal to $mn/2$, and 2 divides $mn$.

(2) In order for $k$ to be an integer, $m$ or $n$ must then have a factor of two, and the statement is proved.

Comment: If $mn=2k$ for some integer $k,$ then $2$ divides $mn$, so $2$ divides $m$ or $n$ by [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you prove a number is prime?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483298/how-do-you-prove-a-number-is-prime). This question is equivalent to asking how to prove that $2$ is prime in $\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 4):

I think it might be easier to prove by contrapositive. Proving your statement is the same as proving that if $m$ and $n$ are both odd, then $mn$ is odd.

Comment: Ah, I see. Was wondering if it the direct proof above worked, also.

Comment: the direct proof works because if $p$ is prime and $p$ divides $mn$, then it is indeed true that $p$ divides $m$ or $p$ divides $n$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $mn$ is even iff $2\mid mn$. But $2$ is prime, so [Euclid's Lemma](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma) applies. Hence $2\mid mn$ iff either $2\mid m$ or $2\mid n$. Now $mn$ is even iff either $m$ is even or $n$ is even.

Answer (score 0):

The really serious problem in your argument is here:

> (2) In order for $k$ to be an integer, $m$ or $n$ must then have a
>   factor of two, and the statement is proved.

That's a problem because it is j*ust a restatement of what you have been asked to prove*.

One good way to start this problem is to suppose that both factors are odd. Then use what you know (and have proved) about the partity of a product of odd numbers.

Your attempt at a direct proof will work once you have proved other important theorems - in particular, the theorem that says that if a prime divides a product it divides one of the factors.